# Linq Group and Aggregate

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to create LINQ query for following TSQL :

```
SELECT [TenantID]
  ,[ABC]
  ,COUNT(*) [TotalSKU], SUM([QtyOnHand]) AS [SOH],SUM([QtyOnHand]*[Price]) AS [SOH_Value]
  ,SUM ([QtyOnOrder]) AS SOO
  ,SUM ([QtyOnOrder]*[Price]) AS [SOO_Value]
  FROM [OMS_StockStatus] GROUP BY  [TenantID], [ABC]
```

I manage this so far :

```
 var res = from a in db.OMS_StockStatus
                      group a by new { a.TenantID, a.ABC } into g
                      select new ABCDashboard { TenantID = g.Key.TenantID, ABC = g.Key.ABC, TotalSKU = g.Count(),
                      SOH =  g.Sum( t => t.QtyOnHand), SOH_Value = g.Aggregate((c,d) => decimal(c.QtyOnHand) * d.Price)};
```

But am getting following error :

> 'System.Linq.IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'Aggregate' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' has some invalid arguments

---

This my entity definition :

```
    public partial class ABCDashboard
{
    public short TenantID { get; set; }
    public string ABC { get; set; }
    public double TotalSKU { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> SOH { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> SOH_Value { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> SOO { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> SOO_Value { get; set; }
}
```

In OMS_StockStatus, QtyOnHand is double? and Price is double?

Comment: Syntax error here? `decimal(c.QtyOnHand)`, should be `(decimal)c.QtyOnHand`, no?

Comment: @RGraham, I tried that initially but was getting error to. Please refer to my answer to Codeman below.

Comment: You need to provide some details about your fields. What type is `SOH_Value`? Is `QtyOnHand` nullable? If so, what do you want the result of `QtyOnHand * Price` to be? If it is to be null, what should `SOH_Value` equate to?

Comment: @RGraham, updated entity in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it with .. SOH_Value = g.Sum(t => ((decimal)t.QtyOnHand) * t.Price)

Comment: I tried that initially, but was getting error on _(decimal)c.QtyOnHand * d.Price_  

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal?' to 'OMS_StockStatus'**  

**Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<OMS_StockStatus,OMS_StockStatus,OMS_StockStatus>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type**

Comment: Then try it like
g.Sum(t => t.QtyOnHand.HasValue ? t.QtyOnHand : 0m * t.Price)
so he will use the decimal value or if it is null he will use 0 for calculation with t.Price